# Forcing Flow Distinct

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Updates
(
    UpdateId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ObjectId INT NOT NULL
)
```

Essentially tracking updates to objects with an increasing ID.

The consumer of this table will select a chunk of 100 distinct object IDs, ordered by `UpdateId` and starting from a specific `UpdateId`. Essentially, keeping track of where it left off and then querying for any updates.

I've found this to be an interesting optimization problem because I've only been able to generate a maximally optimal query plan by writing queries that *happen* to do what I want due to indexes, but do not *guarantee* what I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 ObjectId
FROM Updates
WHERE UpdateId > @fromUpdateId
```

Where `@fromUpdateId` is a stored procedure parameter.

With a plan of:

```
SELECT <- TOP <- Hash match (flow distinct, 100 rows touched) <- Index seek
```

Due to the seek on the `UpdateId` index being used, the results are already nice and ordered from lowest to highest update ID like I want. And this generates a *flow distinct* plan, which is what I want. But the ordering obviously isn't guaranteed behavior, so I don't want to use it.

This trick also results in the same query plan (though with a redundant TOP):

```
WITH ids AS
(
    SELECT ObjectId
    FROM Updates
    WHERE UpdateId > @fromUpdateId
    ORDER BY UpdateId OFFSET 0 ROWS
)
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 ObjectId FROM ids
```

Though, I'm not sure (and suspect not) if this truly guarantees ordering.

One query I hoped SQL Server would be smart enough to simplify was this, but it ends up generating a very bad query plan:

```
SELECT TOP 100 ObjectId
FROM Updates
WHERE UpdateId > @fromUpdateId
GROUP BY ObjectId
ORDER BY MIN(UpdateId)
```

With a plan of:

```
SELECT <- Top N Sort <- Hash Match aggregate (50,000+ rows touched) <- Index Seek
```

I'm trying to find a way to generate an optimal plan with an index seek on `UpdateId` and a *flow distinct* to remove duplicate `ObjectId`s. Any ideas?

[Sample data](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a05400310a127188b949aa25990d1c17) if you want it. Objects will rarely have more than one update, and should almost never have more than one within a set of 100 rows, which is why I'm after a *flow distinct*, unless there's something better I don't know of? However,  there is no guarantee that a single `ObjectId` won't have more than 100 rows in the table. The table has over 1,000,000 rows and is expected to grow rapidly.

Assume the user of this has another way to find the appropriate next `@fromUpdateId`. No need to return it in this query.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The SQL Server optimizer **cannot** produce the execution plan you are after with the guarantee you need, because the *Hash Match Flow Distinct* operator is not order-preserving.

> Though, I'm not sure (and suspect not) if this truly guarantees ordering.

You may *observe* order preservation in many cases, but this is an implementation detail; there is no guarantee, so you cannot rely on it. As always, presentation order can only be guaranteed by a top-level `ORDER BY` clause.

#### Example

The script below shows that Hash Match Flow Distinct does not preserve order. It sets up the table in question with matching numbers 1-50,000 in both columns:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Updates', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.Updates;
GO
CREATE TABLE Updates
(
    UpdateId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    ObjectId INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Updates_UpdateId PRIMARY KEY (UpdateId)
);
GO
INSERT dbo.Updates (ObjectId)
SELECT TOP (50000)
    ObjectId =
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY C1.[object_id]) 
FROM sys.columns AS C1
CROSS JOIN sys.columns AS C2
ORDER BY
    ObjectId;
```

The test query is:

```
DECLARE @Rows bigint = 50000;

-- Optimized for 1 row, but will be 50,000 when executed
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@Rows)
    U.ObjectId 
FROM dbo.Updates AS U
WHERE 
    U.UpdateId > 0
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@Rows = 1));
```

The estimated plan shows an index seek and flow distinct:

[image: Estimated plan]

The output certainly seems ordered to start with:

[image: Start of results]

...but further down values start to go 'missing':

[image: Pattern breaking down]

...and eventually:

[image: Chaos breaks out]

The explanation in this particular case, is that the hash operator spills:

[image: Post-execution plan]

Once a partition spills, all rows that hash to the same partition also spill. Spilled partitions are processed later, breaking the expectation that distinct values encountered will be emitted immediately in the sequence they are received.

---

There are many ways to write an efficient query to produce the ordered result you want, such as recursion or using a cursor. However, it cannot be done using *Hash Match Flow Distinct*.

Answer (score 11):

I'm unsatisfied with this answer because I couldn't manage to get a flow distinct operator along with results that were guaranteed to be correct. However, I have an alternative which should get good performance along with correct results. Unfortunately it requires that a nonclustered index be created on the table.

I approached this problem by trying to think of a combination of columns that I could `ORDER BY` and get the correct results after applying `DISTINCT` to them. The minimum value of `UpdateId` per `ObjectId` along with `ObjectId` is one such combination. However, directly asking for the minimum `UpdateId` seems to result in reading all rows from the table. Instead, we can indirectly ask for the minimum value of `UpdateId` with another join to the table. The idea is to scan the `Updates` table in order, throw out any rows for which `UpdateId` isn't the minimum value for that row's `ObjectId`, and keep the first 100 rows. Based on your description of the data distribution we shouldn't need to throw out very many rows.

For data prep, I put 1 million rows into a table with 2 rows for each distinct ObjectId:

```
INSERT INTO Updates WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT t.RN / 2
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP 1000000 -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
    FROM master..spt_values t1
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
) t;

CREATE INDEX IX On Updates (Objectid, UpdateId);
```

The nonclustered index on `Objectid` and `UpdateId` is important. It allows us to efficiently throw out rows that don't have the minimum `UpdateId` per `Objectid`. There are many ways to write a query that matches the description above. Here's one such way using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DECLARE @fromUpdateId INT = 9999;
SELECT ObjectId
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 u1.UpdateId, u1.ObjectId
    FROM Updates u1
    WHERE UpdateId > @fromUpdateId
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Updates u2
        WHERE u2.UpdateId > @fromUpdateId
        AND u1.ObjectId = u2.ObjectId
        AND u2.UpdateId < u1.UpdateId
    )
    ORDER BY u1.UpdateId, u1.ObjectId
) t;
```

Here's a picture of the [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1cd1F0IZ):

[image: query plan]

In the best case SQL Server will only do 100 index seeks against the nonclustered index. To simulate getting very unlucky I changed the query to return the first 5000 rows to the client. That resulted in 9999 index seeks, so it's like getting an average of 100 rows per distinct `ObjectId`. Here is the output from `SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON`:

> Table 'Updates'. Scan count 10000, logical reads 31900, physical reads 0
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 42 ms.

Answer (score 9):

I love the question - Flow Distinct is one of my favourite operators.

Now, the *guarantee* is the problem. When you think about the FD operator pulling rows from the Seek operator in an ordered fashion, producing each row as it determines it to be unique, this will give you the rows in the right order. But it's hard to know whether there might be some scenarios where the FD doesn't handle a single row at a time.

Theoretically, the FD could request 100 rows from the Seek, and produce them in whatever order it needs them.

The query hints `OPTION (FAST 1, MAXDOP 1)` could help, because it'll avoid getting more rows than it needs from the Seek operator. Is it a *guarantee* though? Not quite. It could still decide to pull a page of rows at a time, or something like that.

I think with `OPTION (FAST 1, MAXDOP 1)`, your `OFFSET` version would give you a lot of **confidence** about the order, but it's not a guarantee.

Comment: As I've understood it, the problem is that the Flow Distinct operator uses a hash table that can spill to disk.  When there's a spill, rows that can be processed using the portion still in RAM are processed immediately, but the other rows aren't processed until the spilled data is read back from disk.  From what I can tell, any operator using a hash table (such as a Hash Join) is not guaranteed to preserve order due to its spilling behavior.

Comment: Correct. See the answer by Paul White.